# Conflito no PHP ao usar form dentro do form?

Tags: php, html

Não sei se é possível, mas tive a necessidade de usar um form dentro do outro, como neste exemplo:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="enviar_cadastro" name="enviar_cadastro">
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="outra_acao_1" name="outra_acao_1">
  </form>
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="outra_acao_2" name="outra_acao_2">
  </form>  
</form>
```

Mas dá conflito no `PHP`, não é possível mesmo usar um form dentro do outro ou existe alguma forma correta?

Comment: pq precisa de um form dentro de outro? deve ter outro jeito de fazer sim.

Comment: Não existe `<form>` dentro de outro, isso é um erro! porque está fazendo assim, qual os motivos que levaram a chegar a essa implementação?

Comment: Entendi. Sempre tive essa dúvida, mas nunca parei para perguntar. Se não existe form dentro do form vou pensar em outras possibilidades. Obrigado!